# Frictional spin effect for 3D graphics?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, graphics3d, dynamic, interactive

Even though most functionalities on the Wolfram Player, Wolfram Cloud, and Cloud Notebooks are broken and unusable, there is however one nice thing: **momentum dissipation**, this is an 'accelerated slow down' effect you get when you spin 3D graphics with your finger.

[image]

*Is there a way to replicate this effect in Mathematica (or perhaps on a touchscreen Windows or Linux screen)*?

The above screencap was recorded from a cloud notebook with the Wolfram Player on iOS 11, after I spun it. Don't ask me why it's monochromatic, just another bug I guess.

Comment: Code works as is for me:  `Graph3D[Table[i -> Mod[i^2, 74], {i, 100}]]` on Windows 7, *Mathematica* 11.1.1.  And is shows up as essentially "light blue".  But I agree with @b3m2a1 that this is a duplicate.